# jQuery tabs content via ajax

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't working? http://jsfiddle.net/87pWn/

I basically copied the source from here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

`$(anchor.hash)` should be `$('a.hash')`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load in content via XMLHttpRequest with a relative base path.

```
<li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
```

When you click on a link, the code is trying to take the content from "http://jsfiddle.net/87pWn/ajax/content1.html", which is why the error handler is being fired.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. Rather than the content not loading, I'm wondering more about why the tabs don't look like tabs but rather a list.

Answer (score 0):

You must select jQuery 1.8.2 or higher. Also you must select jQuery UI, because jQuery UI is main thing you need to see tabs.